# DiffOrig, but show the patch

Tags: vimdiff

Vim help suggests a nice command to show a side-by-side diff of the current buffer since the last save:

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_
    \ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis
```

I'm wondered how to do the same, but show a patch instead (like running `diff -u`) in a new window.

Comment: Please don’t put answers in the question. Post your own answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
command! PatchOrig silent %y | vert new | set bt=nofile | put | 0d_ | set ft=diff | silent %!diff -u # -
```